# Terminal line wrapping

Tags: bash, terminal

My Bash prompt seems to be wrapping lines really inefficiently. Here is an example to show what I mean:

[image]

I would like the commands that I am typing to continue onto the next line if the command length exceeds the window size.

My PS1 variable in the bashrc file is:

```
PS1='\e[0;36m\u \W: \e[m';
```

Perhaps tweaking this will help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the formatting sequences in escaped square brackets to let the terminal know that these characters aren't actually printed (for width calculations):

```
PS1='\[\e[0;36m\]\u \W: \[\e[m\]';
```

More details [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3275/submit-your-blog-post-for-the-super-user-contest-here/3292#3292) in section *Colors*.

<sup>Edited to link to original submission on Meta, since whoever copied it to Blog.SU messed up pretty much everything.</sup>